# Rails Site link on Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, web

I just published a website in Rails and shared it on Facebook but I had a problem

Normally when I post a site link on facebook, it would be like this, allow me to edit things

[image]

but my site , it was like this.

[image]

Is there anybody who knows what going on :(

Answer (score -1):

are you familiar with what is called favicon? Follow this instruction [here](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-tip-adding-a-favicon-to-your-website/) to show favicon on your ruby project and have it display image on facebook. You can also try this info from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp)

Comment: Thank you but I found my problem. Its on the opengraph so I need to add meta tags for FB.